# Query DB based off array order / sort array based off another array's values

Tags: php, mysql

So I feel like there is a simple solution to this, but my mind is going blank.

I have an array of IDs, like so:

```
//array in no particular order    
$arr1 = array(456, 5, 9, 2, 470, 3);
```

Now, those are the IDs (primary key) of rows in my database. I need to get the information for all of those, while maintaining that order. I can query the DB just fine, and get results, but what I can't figure out is how to maintain that order. So the result is I want to be able to iterate over the result and spit out the information in this specific order.

Is there a way to tell the MYSQLI query to sort the IDs by this array? Or once I get the result, is there a way to re-order the result to reflect the order in the given array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem.

```
$unorderedArray = array();
$orderedArray = array();
while($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    array_push($unorderedArray, $a);
}
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i++) {
    for($ii = 0; $ii < sizeof($unorderedArray); $ii++) {
        if($list[$i] == $unorderedArray[$ii]['id']) {
            array_push($orderedArray, $unorderedArray[$ii]);
        }
    }
}
```

So first I take the result from the DB and create a multi-dimensional array with it to make it easier to work with. Then I loop through the first array, which is the order I want, and loop through the result array. When there is a match, I push that into a newly constructed array.

The order is preserved because the array's have the same ID's, one just has more information that the other. So the order, the outermost loop, will match every time. This allows me to put the entirety of the DB result in an array with the order of my $list array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,9,17,19,456) ORDER BY id ASC;
```

So, you will get rows that match any `id` and order it `ascending`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized my example was in ascending order (my bad). The problem is the order could be anything, not necessarily ascending. The array could easily be array(9, 5, 19, 456, 17). Updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: If your array is in any order, but you want to get them in ascending or descending use `ASC` or `DESC` respectively and you will get either `5,9,17,19,456` or `456,19,17,9,5`, is that what you want ?

Comment: The given array of ID's is the order. It cannot change. What I'm looking to do is get the result from the query in the same order as the given array. So instead of the result being in an ascending or descending order, I want the order to reflect the given array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, the fastest solution is to do a `SELECT` with a `WHERE ID = number` and repeat it the number of times you have there... do you get it ?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that...I was just hoping there was a way to accomplish this without having to query the DB over and over like that :/

Comment: have you try with out 'ORDER BY'